# How to configure MacOS Network settings per user

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

I want to have different network settings for separate users in MacOS Mojave. The setting I'm changing is in

> Settings -> Network -> Advanced -> Proxies

When I make a change, it is applied to all users on the machine.
But I only want it applied to one user. Is this possible?

Comment: Nope, this is not a per-user setting. You could set it as a separate Network Location, and then easily switch to that Location from the Apple menu (this only shows up in the Apple menu when you have more than one Network Location defined).

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is a definite improvement.